# Get CSS Div to fill available height

Tags: html, css

I have a div with 2 elements.

```
<div id="master">
      <div id="follower"></div>
      <div id="decider"></div>
<div>
```

'master' div has the following CSS properties

```
height:auto;
width:auto;
margin:0;
padding:10px;   
display:block;
```

The 'follower' div has the following CSS properties

```
position:relative;

vertical-align:middle;
height: auto;

display: inline-block;

margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
```

The 'decider' div decides how tall the 'master' div is. Is it possible for the 'follower' div to fill up as much vertical space in the 'master' div as possible?

I tried `height: 100%` but that just made the 'follower' div take up the whole screen (vertically)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The master should have

```
position: relative;
```

and then the follower should have

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

That should work, except in IE6 (which an alarming amount of people are still using, but I would just disregard those and tell them to update their browser)

Comment: Yep that works. However, it (apparently) caused the inline-block setting in 'follower' to be ignored.

Comment: @jameszhao00, that's because a `position: absolute` element is taken out of the document-flow, so there's nothing it can be inline *with*.

Comment: As David said, the element is lifter out of the document flow and as a result any kind of grid system would break.