# Absolutely-positioned repeating background doesn't stretch to fill page

Tags: css, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get CSS Div to fill available height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297453/get-css-div-to-fill-available-height)

Basically I have a CSS set up as follows:

```
   body {
        font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
        background: url(images/body-background-gradient.png) repeat-x #343434;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #background-tile {
        background: url(images/body-background-tile.png) repeat;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: -2;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="background-tile"></div>
        ...
</body>
```

The body has a horizontally-repeating background gradient. I have an empty div (#background-tile) inside the body, which acts as an overlay background - simply a repeating 2x2 pixel square pattern.

The problem is that when the page stretches to more than the height of the browser, the tile pattern doesn't continue to fill the rest of the background, so I end up with a part at the bottom of the page with no tiled background - just the grey background. I've done a good bit of searching but can't find a solution to work.

Screenshot: http://i46.tinypic.com/9i94xf.png

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want the background image to repeat and tile to fill the entire page background, why can't you just set it as a background on the `body`?

Comment: @bfavaretto, nope, not a duplicate, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @daGUY, as you can see in the code, I already have a background gradient image in the background. The background to the <div> is meant to overlay the <body> background.

Comment: But did you try the solution from the link I posted? It's basically adding `bottom: 0` to `#background-tile`.

Comment: Yeah, no joy I'm afraid. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this

```
width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto;
```

It set the dimensions to the height of the screen you are using...not the whole webpage. If that code is relevant to any other part of your code then you may need to find a way around it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but if I remove the width and height properties, it doesn't appear at all - but this is expected as it's an empty <div>.

Comment: I'm confused on how you have the html set up and what exactly it is supposed to look like. Can you post your html?

Comment: Updated. Bascially, the #background-tile <div> should be the size of the full background, no matter how long the page is. But as you can see from the screenshot, the <div> is only the same size as the browser window, so it ends abrupty when scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `body` a position of `relative`, and `.background-tile` a height of `100%` (and get rid of the `min-height`)

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either. Thanks though.

Comment: Do you also need to give `body` a height of 100%?

Comment: I always set the height of `html` and `body` to 100% before I start any layout.